# how to check nodes of one treeview based upon its filtered treeview in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I want to check the nodes of my original treeview nodes based upon its filtered treeview in c# in windows form application.

Example:-

I have a window form which contains a treeview a search box to search child nodes of treeview whose checkbox property is set to true.

Now, Suppose my treeview contains original data now when user types some search text into search box then i search the original treeview any display a temporary treeview of search result that contains search box string in it.

My question is that when user types in search box i display my temporary filtered treeview to it, now when user check any node(parent or child) of temporary treeview i want that the checked node to also get checked in my original treeview.

Thankyou!

Comment: I'm not sure how you are going to show filtered result in tree, but to find a node in both trees, you can assign key to nodes. Find method of `TreeView.Nodes` let you find the node with key.